# dismiss image picker causes crash

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I use un UINavigationCtronller to navigate from to UIViewController A an UIViewController B.
On the view of the UIViewController B, I tap a button and call UIImagePicker

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

ipc.delegate = self;

ipc.allowsEditing = NO;

[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
```

if I tap the 'Cancel' button of UIImagePicker, I call

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker{



[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

UI will return to UIViewController A rather than B

If I tap any place, app crashed.

Welcome any comment

Comment: can you show us your entire ViewControllerB file ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

try

```
[picker.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You want the ViewController that is presenting the picker to dismiss, not the picker itself.